# Is there a way to split a string in reverse (from right to left) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, split

Does anyone know how to get the javascript `String.split(RegEx)` to split from right to left?

Let's use an example say I have a string that I want to split into substrings with a mix of delimiter.

```js
let test_string = 'cat>==dog'
let delimiters = ['>=','==','>','=']            // listed in desired split priority
// skipping code that makes the following regex
let r = new RegExp('(\>\=|\=\=|\>|\=)','g')     // regex for the above delimiters
let ans = test_string.split(r)                  // split string
ans = ans.filter((s)=>s!=='')                   // remove blanks
console.log(ans)
```

In this, the ans returns `['cat','>=','=','dog']`, but what I really want is `['cat','>','==','dog']` with the delimiters being checked from right to left.

My current solution is to reverse all the delimiters, reverse the string, do the split, reverse each substring in the array, and then reverse the whole array. This ends up being pretty damn slow in larger examples.  Maybe someone has a cleaner solution?

Edit:
Another example that might be clearer than my original is that I would want `'A===B'` to split into `['A','=','==','B']`

Comment: Well does your engine support standalone `=` assignment operators?  If not, then you should fail when parsing.

Comment: It will.  The higher level parser allows for operating on operators.  While this is an edge case, I'm using it becasue it is cleaner example.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I miss something, but isn't it simply the question of ordering the delimiter keys properly? That is, `[ '>', '==', '>=', '=' ]` will split first by `>`, then by `==` as desired:

```js
let test_string = 'cat>==dog';
let delimiters = [ '>', '==', '>=', '=' ];
let r = new RegExp('(' + delimiters.map(k => '\\' + k).join('|') + ')');
let ans = test_string.split(r).filter(Boolean);
console.log(ans)
```

Output:

```
[
  "cat",
  ">",
  "==",
  "dog"
]
```

Comments:

- you can build the regex dynamically from your delimiters list
- to filter out empty array items simply use `.filter(Boolean)`

**UPDATE 1** OP has additional requirement to use the original sequence of delimiters, and use them in reverse order. This can be simply done with a `.reverse()`:

```
    let test_string = 'cat>==dog';
    let delimiters = ['>=','==','>','='];
    let r = new RegExp('(' + delimiters.reverse().map(k => '\\' + k).join('|') + ')');
    let ans = test_string.split(r).filter(Boolean);
    console.log(ans)
```

But with this the output is `[ "cat", ">", "=", "=", "dog"]`, not the desired output. So I do not understand these conflicting requirements.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I do build the regex spliter dynamically in my code but I didn't feel it was neccessary for the question.  I just skipped it for a small example and wote it manually. 

My target is to split a string from right to left instead of from left to right, not change the priority order of the delimiters.  Another examble would be 'A===B' should be ['A','=','==','B'] and not ['A','==','=','B'] or ['A','=','=','=','B'].

Comment: @SquishiestGrape: Added UPDATE 1

Answer (score 0):

Done manually by searching for delimiters in the string:

```js
let test_string = 'cat>==dog';
let delimiters = ['>=','==','>','='];

let s = test_string;
let r = [];
while(true) {
  // if no delimiters found in the string, nothing to do
  if(!delimiters.find(d=>s.includes(d))) {
    r.unshift(s);
    break;
  }
  // find the last occurrence of each delimiter in the string,
  // sorted by the position the delimiter ends at
  let m = delimiters
    .map(d=>[d, s.lastIndexOf(d)+d.length])
    .sort(([a,b],[c,d])=>b-d);
  // of the delimiters tied for rightmost position in the string,
  // select the highest priority delimiter
  let [d,i] = m.filter(([_,i])=>i===m[m.length-1][1])
    .sort(([a,b],[c,d])=>
      delimiters.indexOf(c)-delimiters.indexOf(a)).pop();
  // add the delimiter and any substrings to the result
  let t = s.substring(i);
  if(t) r.unshift(t); // don't include empty strings in the result
  r.unshift(d);
  s = s.substring(0,i-d.length);
}
console.log(r);
```

Comment: That is pretty close to how my original code runs, but I will say that yours employs so 
some neat addions and cleaner lines.  I moved to much cleaner and faster code for the forward direction (ie: the code in the question), and was hoping to do the same for the reverse direction.  Unfortunetly, I could not find a way to get the split funtion or the RegEx to run in the reverse direction in javascript.  (I believe .Net has a way to do it with an option, so I was hoping someone might know a trick in javascript)